# RECURSIVE CTE SQL - Find next available Parent

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have parent child relation SQL table

```
LOCATIONDETAIL Table
OID      NAME        PARENTOID
1        HeadSite     0
2        Subsite1     1
3        subsite2     1
4        subsubsite1  2
5        subsubsite2  2
6        subsubsite3  3

RULESETCONFIG
OID     LOCATIONDETAILOID   VALUE
1          1                30
2          4                15
```

If i provide Input as LOCATIONDETAIL 6, i should get RULESETCONFIG value as 30
because for 
LOCATIONDETAIL 6, parentid is 3 and for LOCATIONDETAIL 3 there is no value in RULESETCONFIG,
LOCATIONDETAIL 3 has parent 1 which has value in RULESETCONFIG

if i provide Input as LOCATIONDETAIL 4, i should get RULESETCONFIG value 15

i have code to populate the tree, but don't know how to find the next available Parent

```
;WITH GLOBALHIERARCHY AS
        (
            SELECT A.OID,A.PARENTOID,A.NAME
            FROM LOCATIONDETAIL A
            WHERE OID = @LOCATIONDETAILOID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT A.OID,A.PARENTOID,A.NAME
            FROM LOCATIONDETAIL A INNER JOIN GLOBALHIERARCHY GH ON A.PARENTOID = GH.OID
        )
SELECT * FROM GLOBALHIERARCHY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the next parent with a value.  If you want to see all, remove the top 1 from the final select.

**[dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e5e701518e2e3aa08d505f5054af871d)**

**Example**

```
Declare @Fetch int = 4               

;with cteHB as (
      Select OID
            ,PARENTOID
            ,Lvl=1
            ,NAME 
      From   LOCATIONDETAIL 
      Where  OID=@Fetch
      Union  All
      Select R.OID
            ,R.PARENTOID
            ,P.Lvl+1
            ,R.NAME 
      From   LOCATIONDETAIL R
      Join   cteHB P on P.PARENTOID = R.OID)
Select Top 1
       Lvl = Row_Number() over (Order By A.Lvl Desc )
      ,A.OID
      ,A.PARENTOID
      ,A.NAME
      ,B.Value
From cteHB A
Left Join RULESETCONFIG B on A.OID=B.OID
Where B.VALUE is not null
  and A.OID <> @Fetch
Order By 1 Desc
```

**Returns when @Fetch=4**

```
Lvl OID PARENTOID   NAME        Value
2   2   1           Subsite1    15
```

**Returns when @Fetch=6**

```
Lvl OID PARENTOID   NAME        Value
1   1   0           HeadSite    30
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
;with LV as (
 select OID ID,PARENTOID PID,NAME NAM, VALUE VAL FROM LOCATIONDETAIL
 left join RULESETCONFIG ON LOCATIONDETAILOID=OID
),    GH as (
 select ID gID,PID gPID,NAM gNAM,VAL gVAL from LV where ID=@OID
union all 
 select ID,PID,NAM,VAL FROM LV INNER JOIN GH ON gVAL is NULL AND gPID=ID
)
select * from GH WHERE gVAL>0
```

See here for e little demo: http://rextester.com/OXD40496